# VNC : Console does not accept any keyboard/mouse inputs

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, vnc, vnc-viewer

I have used and configured vnc many a times before but facing this strange issue for the first time. Here are my steps of configuring vnc on Amazon (RHEL 6.2 64-bit, AMI: ami-2fd5441f):

**Server Configuraion**

- Install desktop packages: `# yum -y groupinstall "Desktop" "X Window System"`
- Install vnc server: `# yum -y install tigervnc-server.x86_64 libXfont.x86_64`
- Start vncserver: `# vncserver`
- Enable vncserver to start after the reboot: `# chkconfig vncserver on`
- Either stop iptables or configure them accordingly: `# service iptables stop` and `# chkconfig iptables off`
- append below two lines to `/etc/sysconfig/vncservers`:

`VNCSERVERS="2:ec2-user"` and `VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1280x1024 -nolisten tcp -localhost"`

- append below line to `~/.vnc/xstartup` (this would be ec2-user's home directory): 
  `exec gnome-session`
- Reboot the server: 
  `# reboot`

**Windows client (laptop) configuration**

- Install vnc viewer on windows laptop
- Connect with below string: `hostname_of_server:5901`

  - Also, EC2 security groups are configured accordingly for VNC access.

Now, when I connect using windows vnc client, I get the successfull connection but I get below window where nothing is clickable:

[image]

I have also checked below settings on my vnc client which will allow keyboard/mouse inputs:

[image]

**QUESTION:**
I have never faced this issue before where the VNC console is "NOT CLICKABLE" And I am not able to figure what am I doing wrong. Could you help?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I tried connecting using `gtkvncviewr` installed on ubuntu and the results were exactly the same. I get the window but nothing is clickable.

**ANSWER**:

After spending almost a week freaking out on this issue, I solved it myself. The solution was to update `libX11`. I ran below yum command and things are flying now.

```
yum install libX11
```

Comment: Scroll the window downwards and rightwards. Is there some kind of modal dialog there?

Comment: No, there is none. I tried from different laptop too, but it is the same behavior.

Comment: Slayed, can you please add the solution as an Answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending almost a week freaking out on this issue, I solved it myself. The solution was to update `libX11`. I ran below yum command and things are flying now.

```
yum install libX11
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue. In my case the problem was not related to libX11 but was caused by the screensaver running on the target host (xubuntu).
Killing the screensaver with command below solved the problem.

`pkill -f "xfce4-screensaver"`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the VNC Client on my Windows machine had "View-Only" checkbox enabled.

To resolve it I had to

1. Hover mouse at the top+center of the VNC client screen after connecting to my ubuntu VNC Server
2. Click on "Settings" from the VNC Client (in the top+center menu)
3. Goto "Options" tab in the dialog window that opened up.
4. Spot a checkbox under "General" named "View-Only"
5. And disable it

Answer (score 1):

The culprit in my case was buggy gnome-shell.

`ps -U <user> | grep gnome-shell`

`kill -9 <space seperated pids from above output>`

I got my vnc session recoverd this way.